# Option to 'Enable Client Credentials Flow' not showing

Tags: oauth2, oauth

I'm trying to configure the OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow as described [in the docs here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_client_credentials_setup.htm&type=5).

However, once I go to the connected app I want to configure, I can't find the option `Enable Client Credentials Flow` under the `API (Enable OAuth Settings)` section as described in the docs.

I've been running in circles trying to figure out why but can't manage to find anything out there explaining this.

I've also tried to send an actual request without finishing the configuration but receive the following:

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "grant type not supported"
}
```

Any help would be very welcomed. Many thanks,
Joel

Comment: This is a new feature, it's only available in orgs with Winter '23 release. Check your org's release via status.salesforce.com

Comment: Thanks @identigral, where can I find in the docs that this flow is only available for a future release? Also, I couldn't find any information from my org on the link you provided; I can see a surfer with a 22 on the web UI of my org but I can't actually find more info on the release, any clue?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5&release=240 . For help on status.salesforce.com, click on question mark (top right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @identigral, seems that this feature will only be available on Winter 23 release -> [see release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=release-notes.rn_security_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5&release=240)

Comment: I am getting this after update to Winter23, all settings should be correct. Is this something that should be enabled from support ?
```{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "request not supported on this domain"
}```

Comment: Ok, I figured this out. The domain part of the token endpoint needs to be the my domain address not test/login.salesforce.com, so
`POST {{my_domain_url}}/services/oauth2/token`
and that is even mentioned in the docs